# Navigation graph start destination issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation

- I am using Navigation Graph in an activity as it is the recommended approach to be used for fragments.
- I only want to load fragment based on given condition otherwise do not load i.e., keep the `startDestination` as null.
- Is it possible to do so? I don't want conditional start destination.

Comment: Do you have splash screen in your project. Can you make a simple white fragment and make it as start destination and in that fragment you can check the condition which fragment needs to be shown

Comment: No I don't want conditional startDestination. It should be just skipped till activity exists.

Comment: So If the start destination is null what would happen?

Comment: I mean do not load NavHostFragment. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok then you need to add NavHostFragment Programmatically